# Keycloak - Proxy / Front End Url / Javascript client redirect issue

Tags: vue.js, keycloak, reverse-proxy, keycloak-services

I'm attempting to use Keycloak for some future projects and it's still very new to me so I'm plugging away reading through the docs and searching for issues online but I'm currently stumped on one thing - I have a vuejs app I’ve added as a client (**127.0.0.1:3001**), I have a reverse proxy setup in IIS (**idp.mc.local**) and then a docker container on Windows with keycloak running (**127.0.0.1:8080**), when I attempt to login, instead of being redirected back to the vuejs client I am just getting redirected to the root of the reverse proxy with the state value in the url, as in the network logs in the screenshot below:

[Network logs showing incorrected 'Location' redirect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTIuv.png)

If I don’t set a front end url for the realm and bypass the proxy / hook my vuejs client to login via Keycloak directly on **127.0.0.1:8080**, it redirects to **127.0.0.1:3001/#state**… correctly, as below:

[Network logs showing correct 'Location' redirect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXW2E.png)

I can't spot any way to sort this issue, I thought the front end url for the realm should state the proxy address? I can't see why Keycloak would redirect to it at the end of the login process rather than to my client app url, the redirect_uri is being ignored by keycloak and for some reason taking me back to the root of my proxy domain. If I actually manually visit **127.0.0.1:3001/#state**… with the state value copied in from the incorrect redirect, I log in successfully.

It's baffling me and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I would blame reverse proxy, because it's working without IIS. Make sure you are following: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#_setting-up-a-load-balancer-or-proxy

Comment: Thanks Jan, I'm certain I'm setting something up incorrectly somewhere, just wondered if it was in the settings on Keycloak via the admin panel / standalone xml file. I'll give the same setup a go with Apache as the reverse proxy as I have that installed as well and see if that does the same.

Comment: You shouldn't use `some` proxy configuration. Keycloak requires `specific` proxy configuration, which is described in the Keycloak doc. You can use any proxy (IIS, Apache, Nginx, HAProxy, ....) and you will still have a problem if you don't configure specially for Keycloak needs.

Comment: Yep, understand that, IIS doesn't always play nicely with 'X-Forwarded-For' and 'X-Forwarded-Proto' by the sounds of it, by trying an alternative and setting the headers described in the docs using Apache I might have different results or I might have the same issue and it might be my Keycloak config / settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer did turn out to be an IIS related issue with the setup of Application Request Routing / ARR being the problem. What was needed was to edit the settings for IIS Application Request Routing and uncheck the option:

`Reverse rewrite host in response headers` as can be seen in the image below:

[IIS ARR Checkbox to untick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glvVa.png)

Hopefully this will be helpful for someone else who might have the same issue at some point!